# Render data from local JSON (with dynamic data) in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a json array of objects as shown below, the number of objects can vary as well as the content of the `"units"` array inside the respective object can vary.

```
[{
    "title": "title1",
    "units": [{
            "title": "unittitle1",
            "status": "on",
            "utilization": "76.4"
        },
        {
            "title": "unittitle1",
            "status": "on",
            "utilization": "76.4"
        },
        {
            "title": "unittitle1",
            "status": "on",
            "utilization": "76.4"
        },
        {
            "title": "unittitle1",
            "status": "on",
            "utilization": "76.4"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "title": "title2",
    "units": [{
            "title": "unittitle1",
            "status": "on"
        },
        {
            "title": "unittitle1",
            "status": "on"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

I am calling the above json like this :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import hardwareDetailsData from '../../../assets/json/UnitHardwareDetails.json';
import meter from '../../../assets/images/meter.svg';

class HardwareUnits extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      hardwareDetailsData: []
    };
  }

  render() {
    return hardwareDetailsData.map(hardwareData => (
      <div className="f-14">
        <ul className="list-inline list-pipe">
          <li className="list-inline-item">
            <span className="f-b">{hardwareData.units.title}</span>
            <span className="status-text ml-2 text-success">{hardwareData.units.status}</span>
          </li>
          <li className="list-inline-item">
            <span className="text-warning f-b">{hardwareData.units.utilization}</span>
            <img src={meter} alt="Meter" className="ml-3 icon-meter-size" />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    ));
  }
}

export default HardwareUnits;
```

I am aware that the above code would require unique key for child elements. But, is there a optimal way to achieve the main objective i.e. to render the dynamic content of JSON in the list

Comment: `content of the "units" array inside the respective object can vary` you mean there might be more or less objects with the same signature in the array?

Comment: @Papi only the signature of objects inside the units array may not be indistinct. The signature of parent object will be same

Comment: So take a look at my answer. I mentioned conditional rendering there.

Comment: If my or soroush answer are correct, please accept them so the question can be resolved and closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood you want map in map like so:

```
return hardwareDetailsData.map(({ title, units }) => (
  <div className="title">
    {title}
    units.map({ title, status, utilization}) => (
      <div className="status">{status}</div>
    ));
  </div>
));
```

Keep in mind shadowing, key (as you mentioned) and conditional rendering for `utilization` if it's the case. Also it could be splitted to components.

Answer (score 0):

Your `render` method should be like this:

```
 render() {
    return hardwareDetailsData.map((hardwareItem, index) => (
      <div className="f-14" key={index}>
        <ul className="list-inline list-pipe">
          {
            hardwareItem.units.map((unitItem, index) => (
              <li className="list-inline-item" key={index}>
                <span className="f-b">{unitItem.title}</span>
                <span className="status-text ml-2 text success">{unitItem.status}</span>
                <span className="text-warning f-b">{unitItem.utilization}</span>
                <img src={meter} alt="Meter" className="ml-3 icon-meter-size" />
              </li>
            ))
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    ));
  }
```

Comment: Thank you this is helpful too